# Matching the database records with the textfield value and updating the database in php

Tags: php

I am creating a webpage wherein an admin can update a student's record(here it is the Demand Draft number), it will update the record for a particular student id.
The code I am working is below, the problem is the DD number gets updated for all the records in the database and not for the id mentioned in the textfield.
If anyone could offer a possible solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Here's the code:

```
    <div class="main row">
    <?php
    $connect_mysql=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    $mysql_db=mysql_select_db("mca",$connect_mysql);

    ?>      
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="">
    Enter the student's Registration ID :<span style="padding-left:20px"> <input type="text" id="studentsearch" name="studentsearch"></span>
    </br> </br><span style="padding-left:190px"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="search"></span></br>

    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {

        $id=$_POST['studentsearch'];
        $query1="select 1 from user where id=$id" ;
        $result1=mysql_query($query1) or die("Query Failed:".mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result1)>0)
        {
             echo 'student  present';
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'student not present';
        }
    }
    ?>
    </br>
    </br>Enter the Demand Draft no : <span style="padding-left:46px"><input type="text" name="dd"></span>
    </br></br><span style="padding-left:190px">
    <input name="update" type="submit" value="update"></span><span style="padding-left:10px">
    <input name="clear" type="submit" value="cancel" ></span>
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $connect_mysql=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect"); 
    $mysql_db=mysql_select_db("mca",$connect_mysql);

        $id1=$_POST['studentsearch'];
        $dd=$_POST['dd'];
        $sql="SELECT id FROM user ";
        $result1 =mysql_query($sql,$connect_mysql) or die(mysql_error($connect_mysql));

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
        if($id1=$row['id'])
        {
                $q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd'";
        $result2=mysql_query($q,$connect_mysql) or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());
        }
        mysql_close($connect_mysql);

    }
    ?>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `mysql_` functions are deprecated. I suggest you look into `PDO` instead http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: you are missing your conditional statements in your queries. Right now in both your select and your update you are telling it to apply the operations to every record in each of those tables.

Comment: You forgot th `WHERE` clause when updating, `$q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd' WHERE id=$id";` you don't need the `WHILE` loop. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO` instead of `mysql_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although mysql_ is deprecated, the problem is here

```
$q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd'";
```

This should be

```
$q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd' WHERE id='$id1'";
```

And the same for this line, it needs a WHERE clause

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM user ";
```

AS

```
$sql="SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='$id1'";
```

**EDIT:**

Try this and let me know what your result is

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $connect_mysql=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect"); 
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("mca",$connect_mysql);

    $id1=$_POST['studentsearch'];
    $dd=$_POST['dd'];
    $sql="SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='$id1'";
    $result1 =mysql_query($sql,$connect_mysql) or die(mysql_error($connect_mysql));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
if(($row['id']) == $id1) {
$q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd' WHERE id='$id1'";
$result2=mysql_query($q,$connect_mysql) or die("Query Failed".mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($connect_mysql);

} // Close While Loop
}
```

Add for troubleshooting data issues underneath the `$dd` variable:

```
echo $id1;
echo $dd;
```

Add the following just above the update submit button input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ssresult" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['studentsearch'])) { echo $_POST['studentsearch']; } ?>">
```

And change your code to this:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
$connect_mysql=mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("cannot connect"); 
$mysql_db=mysql_select_db("mca",$connect_mysql);

$id1=$_POST['ssresult'];
$dd=$_POST['dd'];
$sql="SELECT id FROM user WHERE id='$id1'";
$result1 =mysql_query($sql,$connect_mysql) or die(mysql_error($connect_mysql));

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)) {
if(($row['id']) == $id1) {
$q="UPDATE user SET DD='$dd' WHERE id='$id1'";
$result2=mysql_query($q,$connect_mysql) or die("Query  Failed".mysql_error());
}

mysql_close($connect_mysql);

} // Close While Loop
}
```

Comment: even if i use where clause, it delivers the same result..it continues to update all the records in the database instead for a particular id

Comment: I have updated my answer with how the code should be laid out in my opinion, you were missing braces on your while loop so the result set wouldn't returns correctly, also the where clause should have been $id1 looking through your code again

Comment: now nothing is getting updated. The database remains unaffected

Comment: As well as updating the DB, you could always echo the values of your $_POST data so you can see what data is being pushed so underneath $dd = $_POST['dd']'

Add echo $id1; echo $dd;

Comment: echo $id1; doesn't return any result...so how do i make it work now..the values from the textfield are fetched using $_POST, rite?

Comment: When you submit your form the first time the field empties so when you submit using the update button the value has gone from the input box, i have updated my answer with some changes, could you let me know how you get on with this, thanks

Comment: thank u soooooooooooooooooo much,,,,big thanks....its working! its working!! finally...thanks alot :D :D

Comment: No problem, don't forget the mention that mysql_ is deprecated so please look into using PDO instead, happy coding

Comment: @PoojaGangurde Could you mark the answer as correct when you get chance as well please